# Https (SSL Cert) is blocking my media widget on wordpress site

Tags: javascript, wordpress, ssl

Im finishing up a Wordpress site for a client, the sales streaming radio services, so I added an SSL cert to the site.

On the front page, it streams online radio and my widget (from a third party company) isn't loading due to the https. Is there a way I could possibly just have the ssl on the pages specific to credit card info, or maybe something else just to get the media player to work. Im like 80% done with this client.
Please Help

Comment: what is error please share

Comment: check in browser console

Comment: I just get a "Loading..."

Comment: You're probably going to have to figure out how to get your third party widget to load over HTTPS. When you buy a cert, it's for a domain, and the key is physically on the server. As far as I know there isn't a way to choose which pages are HTTPS and which aren't on the same domain, if SSL is present.

Comment: please check browser console it will give errors about it

Answer (score 0):

you have to replace all http:// to https:// in all external content load call like css,  javascript, fonts external content load and if you use base url then it should be change to https://

Comment: The code that is given to me by the 3rd party streaming service is :         <div class="cc_player" data-username="gaskins">Loading ...</div> so its not much I can do with it

Comment: Is there a way to get the cert to trust the plugin

Comment: @Clay have you done general settings this will help you https://managewp.com/wordpress-ssl-settings-and-how-to-resolve-mixed-content-warnings

Comment: and check this plugin also will help you https://wordpress.org/plugins/ssl-insecure-content-fixer/

Comment: I just ended up using the a tune in App. The company my client went through didn't consult with me before choosing them. Their media browser and code was antiquated. so all in all problem solve just found a work around Thanks for your help